# Reddit API - Pull Information from Json using foreach()

Tags: php, foreach, json, reddit

I am trying to pull the title and url from the Reddit JSON API using PHP's foreach() loop. [Here is what the JSON outputs when used in print_r.](http://enigmo.co/reddit-json/)

Here is the code I have so far...

```
$string_reddit = file_get_contents("http://reddit.com/hot.json");
$json = json_decode($string_reddit, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string_reddit = file_get_contents("http://reddit.com/hot.json");
$json = json_decode($string_reddit, true);  

$children = $json['data']['children'];
foreach ($children as $child){
    $title = $child['data']['title'];
    $url = $child['data']['url'];
}
```

Comment: I added echo($title); echo"<br />"; and it only seems to be outputting the first and last entries in the .json.